# Should I use nofollow when cross-linking between two sites I own on a single domain?

Tags: seo, nofollow

I currently maintain both a retail store and a repository of user manuals for those products. These websites are both situated on the same domain (*mystore.com* and *manuals.mystore.com* respectively).

At present, on many individual manuals, I have added a *"Buy From Mystore.com"* button, linking to the appropriate page on the retail store. In addition to these links, I'd also like to add a small banner on some categories (say Accessories) linking to the appropriate section of the retail store in a similar vain.

I was just wondering if it is recommended to use nofollow on these links, or whether I am safe to exclude this as they are not necessarily pay links and link to relevant content of our own.

Thanks for reading. I apologize if any info is needed, I am happy to elaborate if needed.

Comment: Personally if these manuals are relevant to the main site you should try to merge them into one solid domain, as this could help your search rankings.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason for specifying `nofollow` on these links (on the same domain).

`nofollow` only needs to be used on untrusted or paid-for links.